What are "copies" in a digital context?
"Copies" are apparently defined as:

material objects, other than phonorecords, in which a work is fixed by any method now known or later developed, and from which the work can be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid of a machine or device.

This clearly states that copies are "material" objects. A radio transmission, say, which is physical but presumably not material, would not itself be a "copy". The right to make it would be separately covered by copyright law.
How does this apply in a virtual context? I have one physical computer with one physical hard drive. I download a JPEG off the Internet, so now the JPEG can be reproduced from my hard drive. So my hard drive itself is a "copy" of the JPEG? If I copy-paste the file 15 times on my desktop, do I have one "copy" still, or do I have 15? (Does it matter if my filesystem does deduplication and writes the JPEG data 1 vs. 15 times onto the same hard drive?)
If I have one JPEG file and I open it and look at it, it is (at least temporarily) fixed in and can be physically reproduced from the hard drive, the memory, and also the illuminated pixels. So do I now have 3 copies? Or is the whole computer still itself one copy?
If I throw all the JPEGs in the recycle bin and empty it, do I now have 0 copies? Or do I likely still have one or several, because someone could come by and forensically recover the data?
If I sell a CD that is the same track 15 times in a row, do I need a license to distribute one "copy" of the track for every CD, or 15? (Or do these behave importantly differently as "phonorecords"?)
Generally, does the law recognize the virtual abstraction of "files" or what a computer would call "copies", or is it stuck only talking about the physical media that hold them, due to the statutory definition? Or is it working in some hybrid space where it recognizes particular sets of physical sub-areas of disks as distinct "material" "objects"?

If it walks like a duck and talks like a duck, it's a duck. So anything that acts like a copy is a copy. Your hard drive contains a copy when you download. If you then duplicate that file, you have two copies. The fact that the OS optimizes this to reduce the actual disk space used is probably irrelevant, they like independent copies (if you modify one of them, it will split this off).

The piece of your hard drive where each file is stored is a copy
There are tools that can be used to identify that particular piece. Note that, in general, this will not be a contiguous piece
It’s no different to make a copy in part of a blank notebook - those pages where the writing is are the copy and the blank pages aren’t.
